# Output signal F is U if not declared in testbench. Up counter isn't incrementing properly

Tags: vhdl

My VHDL 4 bit synchronous uncounter isnt functioning properly. If I do not declare the signal F as 0 then my value will be U and if i do declare it, it will stay at 0. It's supposed to return to 0 when the reset is low or when the up counter would reach its maximum value (1111).

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity upcount is
    Port ( n : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 1);
           clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           rst : in STD_LOGIC;
           F : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end upcount;

architecture Behavioral of upcount is

signal temp : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000"; --delcare temp register


begin --begin behavioral
process(clk,rst,n) --delcare our process 
begin --begin process

    if (rst = '0' or temp = "1111") then 
    temp <= "0000"; --when our reset is in active low or F is at max value we reset F to 0 
    elsif( falling_edge(clk) ) then -- when our clock is low we are incrememnting f 
    temp <= temp + 1; --incrementing 1 to our F
    end if; -- this is our 4 bit up counter that incremements 1


end process; --end main process

f <= temp; --push temp into f

end Behavioral; --end behavioral

end behavioral;
```

TESTBENCH CODE

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity upcount is
--  Port ( );
end upcount;

architecture Behavioral of upcount is

COMPONENT upcounter 
PORT (n : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 1); 
      clk, rst : in std_logic; 
      f : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)); --port map our signals 
END COMPONENT;

signal clk, rst : std_logic;
signal n : std_logic_vector(2 downto 1);
signal f : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); --delcare our signals that are getting mapped



begin

UUT : upcounter PORT MAP (
n => n,
clk => clk, 
rst => rst,
f => f); --map our ports

tb : PROCESS 
begin 

RST <= '0'; --set our reset to active
n <= "00";
f <= "0000"; --declare f and n

CLK <= '1';
wait for 20 ns;
CLK <= '0';
wait for 20 ns;

end process;



end behavioral;
```

My clock functions correctly and the waveforms show that but I'm not seeing any values of f changing. My code is not complete as you'll see that n is not being used. I intend to implement that portion of the code later but for this problems sake it is unrelated to the rest of the code.
I tried to implement my 4 bit upcounter using behavioral modeling and I can't seem to find the issue. If anyone could provide some insight on what I'm missing or doing incorrectly would very much help.

Answer (score 1):

`f` is driven from your UUT and the `tb` process, causing multiple drivers. If you remove the assignment from the `tb` process it will only be driven from the connection to the UUT.

Your `rst` is held at 0, which holds the UUT in reset, which why you only ever see "0000" on `f` when there are no multiple drivers present.